# Where to put resources (css, js) when working with multi folders environment

Tags: java, css, jsp, servlets

I have a problem.

This is my folders tree

```
WEB-INF
---adminarea
   ---some jsp files
---jspf
---view
   ---error
   ---userarea
      some jsp files
Resources
---css
---js 
---img
```

When I work with servlet and for example I call servlet mapped `/admin` everythings works but when I ask for a servlet mapped `/admin/admin_page` that forward the request and response to an jsp file inside a`dminarea` folder I get an error. In particulary all the resources css, js and img are not found. The system try to find the resources in ...My_project/admin/resources/  but the resources aren't there. How can I fix the problem in the way that all the file in my project wherever they are could reach correctly the resources?

This is the way I call the resources the header

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

by giving full path to your CSS or JS or any static resources like Image folder as below

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">
```

try this one it may help you